# About Sappho's "Hector and Andromacha" poem

Tags: poetry, greek-language, sappho

In a relatively short while, I'll have to write a blog post on this poem, so I've been doing some research into the sources. The first is P.Oxy. 1232, an image of which is the following.

[image: Image of P.Oxy.1232]

A later source is P.Oxy. 2076, with image below.

[image: Image of P.Oxy. 2076]

From these, I can find most of what the text at [Greek Wikisource (very end of page)](https://el.wikisource.org/wiki/%CE%8E%CE%BC%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%B9_%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9_%CE%95%CF%80%CE%B9%CE%B8%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%AC%CE%BC%CE%B9%CE%B1) has. However, there is a bit that is not in these images. From what I see on [Grenfell and Hunt's book on the Oxyrhynchus Papyri (HUGE DOCUMENT, Firefox crashed while I tried to find the page of the below image)](https://ia600204.us.archive.org/29/items/oxyrhynchusppt1000grenuoft/oxyrhynchusppt1000grenuoft.pdf), P.Oxy.1232 is supposed to have a couple other fragments, one of which they transcribe as:

[image: transcription of extra fragment of P.Oxy. 1232]

If this is a scrap of papyrus in no way connected to the image above, on what basis do they include it in the poem of the two images above?

Comment: Hey, I got to say, I feel bad because this site might not be the best site in terms of giving you a good answer, but I've really enjoyed your questions so far.

Comment: @hamlet glad you did. You may also enjoy my blog posts about Sappho (when I post them), btw. Anyways, any ideas for a better site to post these questions to? I asked on main meta and I was pointed to Latin, Linguistics and Literature. Would any of these be better suited? Perhaps Latin, because, you know, "antiquities"? Any suggestions of your own to add to this list?

Comment: @MickG I think you would get better exposure on Latin.SE, which explicitly allows Ancient Greek questions (at least until a Greek proposal gains traction). A great deal of Latinists are classicists who have also studied Greek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After P.Oxy. 2076, it becomes apparent (as I said also in [my blog post about this poem](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/06/hector-and-andromacha.html)) that the lines of the spare scrap join rather nicely with some of those of P.Oxy. 2076.

Before that papyrus, however, there seems to be no reason to put the two together other than the P.Oxy. number. Concerning that, I posted [a question on Latin SE](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/how-are-p-oxy-numbers-chosen).

Why Edmonds joined the scrap to column 1 and left column 2 separate is a mystery. He probably just saw a completion that could have made them fit together, and thought maybe this was nearer to the top of the roll than the other column. He would have to answer that himself. It was entirely his call.